# Trying to make a query with JPA

Tags: mysql, database, jpa

I'm trying to make a query with JPA which does the following:

I have a User which has a reference ( as foreign key ) to an "account_id" which is the ID of the Account. Now I have the ID of the account and 
I try to query for the User ID

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.account_id LIKE :account
```

:account is the parameter ID of the account I have.

image to clarify:
[image]

For the moment I still get the following error:

```html
Warning:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB UserFacade, method: public domain.User dao.UserFacade.findOnAccount(long)
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy346.findOnAccount(Unknown Source)
 at dao.__EJB31_Generated__UserFacade__Intf____Bean__.findOnAccount(Unknown Source)
 at servlet.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:77)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.account_id LIKE :account]. 
[27, 39] The state field path 'u.account_id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1585)
 at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:456)
 at dao.UserFacade.findOnAccount(UserFacade.java:41)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
 at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
 ... 33 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.account_id LIKE :account]. 
[27, 39] The state field path 'u.account_id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1583)
 ... 63 more

Severe:   javax.ejb.EJBException
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy346.findOnAccount(Unknown Source)
 at dao.__EJB31_Generated__UserFacade__Intf____Bean__.findOnAccount(Unknown Source)
 at servlet.LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:77)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.account_id LIKE :account]. 
[27, 39] The state field path 'u.account_id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1585)
 at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:456)
 at dao.UserFacade.findOnAccount(UserFacade.java:41)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
 at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
 at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
 ... 33 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.account_id LIKE :account]. 
[27, 39] The state field path 'u.account_id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1583)
 ... 63 more
```

Comment: posting the actual User/Account classes would reveal your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `User` has a field `account`, use something like this

```
SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.account.id = :accountId
```

As a side note, your query would work in Hibernate (with `=` instead of `LIKE` because `account_id` is probably a number), because Hibernate passes whatever it doesn't recognize as mapped field directly into SQL.

Comment: You just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering you have field names similar to the columns names in table. You can navigate to the account id of user using the path expressions. Your query will be as below

```
SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.account.id = :accountId
```

OR

```
SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.account.id = ?1
```

first is called as named parameter while other method is called as positional parameters. You can set the parameters using

```
 query.setParameter(1,accountId); // OR
 query.setParameter("accountId", accountId);
```

You can refer [query parameters in jpa](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/03/19/jpa-query-parameters/)

Please note that when you are dealing with JPA, then you are dealing with **entities** and **not database tables**. so whatever you write in jpql queries, they should be **entity field names** in path expressions and **not database table column names.**

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already knew about the named and positional parameters, but I thought my query would be correct. It seems the first query did it for me.

Comment: I've written in the last paragraph why the query provided by Predrag works and not yours.

Comment: Thanks to clarify, I was never sure if I needed to refer to the column names of the DB or the entities. Now i'll keep to entity fields names. So if a User has a location field ( and a location has a street field ) i can query on street like `SELECT u FROM user u WHERE u.location.street = :someStreet`

Comment: @Tomato you got it right :) JPA are entities, entities are objects, objects have fields. We navigate fields only. Not dealing with database directly through application, isn't it the purpose of jpa/